# How to hide a div and its container when the container is clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a div and its container when the container is clicked.

Here is what I've been already trying :

HTML

```
<p>text to unhide</p>
<div id="container">
<div id="div"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container { z-index:2998; position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0; background: green; }
#div { z-index:2999; position:fixed; top:15%; left:10%; width:80%; height:70%; background: yellow; }
p { color:#000; text-align:center; font-size:25px; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#container").mouseup(function(e)
{
    var subject = $("#div"); 

    if(e.target.id != subject.attr('id') && !subject.has(e.target).length)
    {
        subject.fadeOut();
    }
});
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7jzrd0zt/

As it is, the yellow `#div` can be hidden, but not the green `#container`.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Well in you code, you are fading out only the yellow  `#div`, if you need to hide the container, you should do `$(this).fadeOut();` instead - which will fade out the green container as well - http://jsfiddle.net/7jzrd0zt/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the subject you need to hide subjects parent.

```
$(subject).parent().hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions, but since you're using id's and the markup is simple, you can just do `$("#container").fadeOut()` instead of `subject.fadeOut()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jzrd0zt/2/

Since your listener is listening on the `#container` itself, you could also do `$(this).fadeOut()`.  `this` will refer to the element listening to the event.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the target is not the subject. If not, you can call `$(this).fadeOut()` and hide the container (with the `subject`), revealing the text.

Here's the script:

```
$('#container').on('click', function(e) {
    var $subject = $('#div');
    if ($(e.target).is($subject) === false) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jzrd0zt/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for hide and show div

```
<p id='ptest'>text to unhide</p>
<div id="container">
<div id="div"></div>
</div>    

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#container").mouseup(function(e)
    {
        $("#container").hide();
    });
    $("#ptest").mouseup(function(e)
    {
        $("#container").show();
    });
});
```